# How to fix value error 'too many values to unpack (expected 2)' that makes in traing CIFAR10 dataset using Torch framework

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am going to train CIFAR10 dataset in the Torch framework. First I download this dataset and load it with two first functions. Then I train using the Pytorch framework. Eventually, I receive this error. It is my appreciate if you help to fix it. My code is long, so I put the summary of functions using in train.

too many values to unpack (expected 2)

```
def load_cifar10_batch(filename):
    """ Load a single batch from CIFAR10 """
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        datadict = pickle.load(f, encoding='bytes')
        X=datadict[b'data']
        Y = datadict[b'labels']
        X = X.reshape(10000, 3, 32, 32).transpose(0, 2, 3, 1).astype('float')
        Y = np.array(Y)
    return X, Y



def load_cifar10(dir):
        """ Load all batches of CIFAR10 """
        # load train batch file
        xs = []
        ys = []
        for i in range(1, 6):
            filename = os.path.join(dir, 'data_batch_%d' % i)
            X, Y = load_cifar10_batch(filename)
            xs.append(X)
            ys.append(Y)
        Xtr = np.concatenate(xs)
        Ytr = np.concatenate(ys)
        del X, Y
        # load test batch
        Xte, Yte = load_cifar10_batch(os.path.join(dir, 'test_batch'))
        return Xtr, Ytr, Xte, Yte  

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = load_cifar10('cifar-10-batches-py') 

'''we used just test set, because of the train set is so big file for train '''
from torch.utils.data import random_split
val_size = 3000
train_size = len(X_test) - val_size


train_ds, val_ds = random_split(X_test, [train_size, val_size])

len(train_ds), len(val_ds)

'''loading data  '''
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import DataLoader

batch_size=16
train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, pin_memory=True)
val_dl = DataLoader(val_ds, batch_size, num_workers=4, pin_memory=True)

'''our model '''
class Cifar10CnnModel(ImageClassificationBase):
    def __init__(self):
        
    def forward(self, xb):
        return self.network(xb)

'''ImageClassificationBase'''
class ImageClassificationBase(nn.Module):
    def training_step(self, batch):
        images, labels = batch 
        out = self(images)                  # Generate predictions
        loss = F.cross_entropy(out, labels) # Calculate loss
        accu = accuracy(out,labels)
        return loss,accu
   

def fit(model, train_loader, val_loader,epochs=2,learning_rate=0.001):
    best_valid = None
    history = []
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), learning_rate,weight_decay=0.0005)
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        # Training Phase 
        model.train()
        train_losses = []
        train_accuracy = []
        for batch in tqdm(train_loader):
            loss,accu = model.training_step(batch)
            train_losses.append(loss)
            train_accuracy.append(accu)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
        # Validation phase
        result = evaluate(model, val_loader)
        result['train_loss'] = torch.stack(train_losses).mean().item()
        result['train_accuracy'] = torch.stack(train_accuracy).mean().item()
        model.epoch_end(epoch, result)
        if(best_valid == None or best_valid<result['Accuracy']):
            best_valid=result['Accuracy']
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'cifar10-cnn.pth')
        history.append(result)
    return history

'''But the call to this function'''

''' train dataset '''
history = fit(model, train_dl, val_dl)


'''gives this error'''


  0%|                                                                                          |   0/438 [00:31<?, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [44], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 history = fit(model, train_dl, val_dl)

Input In [43], in fit(model, train_loader, val_loader, epochs, learning_rate)
      9 train_accuracy = []
     10 for batch in tqdm(train_loader):
---> 11     loss,accu = model.training_step(batch)
     12     train_losses.append(loss)
     13     train_accuracy.append(accu)



  Input In [27], in ImageClassificationBase.training_step(self, batch)
          7 def training_step(self, batch):
    ----> 8     images, labels = batch 
          9     out = self(images)                  # Generate predictions
         10     loss = F.cross_entropy(out, labels) # Calculate loss
    
    ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: complete traceback is required. please present a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You perform the split on `X_test` only, losing the labels this way.

Try something like

```
dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(torch.from_numpy(X_test), torch.from_numpy(y_test))
train_ds, val_ds = random_split(dataset, [train_size, val_size])
```